# Pipe in MacOS always reads too few bytes (but Linux works)

Tags: c, linux, macos, pipe

This code works beautifully in Linux, but with MacOS it always fails to read the tree (it will read too bytes). It works with redirection from a file. It reads when a file is explicitly opened. But on a pipe, always too few bytes.

```
// Load the saved tree

    uint16_t treeBytes = 0;

    read(fileIn, &treeBytes, sizeof(treeBytes));

    if (verbose) { printf("tree (%u)\n", treeBytes); }

    uint8_t  savedTree[treeBytes];

    int readSz = read(fileIn, savedTree, treeBytes);
    if (readSz != treeBytes)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d != %u: ", readSz, treeBytes);
            ERROR("Truncated tree read");
    }
```

Comment: There is not enough context in your question (e.g. pipe? what pipe??). Please provide a [mcve] including exact  input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: It reads a tree (encoded in postfix). The size of the tree is given in TreeBytes (and is correct). On Linux, it will read that many bytes and all is good. On MacOS, it reads a smaller number. The input is binary, but if you really want it I can post a dump. It's not really a question of what is in the input, but why the read on the pipe (stdin) always comes up short. fileIn may be a file descriptor from open(), or it may be a redirect from stdin. In which case it works fine. But if it is a pipe, nope.

Comment: How big is `TreeBytes`? How about putting your `read()` in a loop till you get the whole tree read in?

Comment: On 2017-05-28 at 18:10:30Z, [Augustine Calmet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8076673/augustine-calmet) added an ['answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44230474/15168) that was deleted as 'not an answer' because it said: _You're right. I was relying on read() getting that I wanted since I knew the file was big enough, but had forgotten that since I was using independent write() calls at the other end of the pipe() that a context switch could cause an incomplete read. I should have known better, I was just getting lazy. Thanks._

Answer (score 3):

There are two bugs here:

1. You aren't checking the return from the first `read()` call. There are four possible returns here, three of which will break your program: -1 on error, 0 on abnormal close (typical for sockets only), 1 for a short read, and 2 (`sizeof(treeBytes)`) for a successful read. Don't assume.
2. You are collapsing those three failure cases as one in your second `read()`, which probably explains your reported symptom. There is nothing mandating that `read()` must block until it gets `treeBytes` from the pipe. It is allowed to return 1 byte at a time for a blocking FD, and 0 for a nonblocking FD. As Mark Sechell comented above, read in a loop until you have as many bytes as you expect *or* you hit an error case.